# How do Java decompilers discern a for-loop from a while-loop?

Tags: java, decompiling

Consider these two methods:

```
public static void forLoop(int start, int limit) {
    for (int i = start; i < limit; i++) {

    }
}

public static void whileLoop(int start, int limit) {
    int i = start;
    while (i < limit) {
        i++;
    }
}
```

When compiled, they produce the bytecode (this is the verbose output of `javap`):

```
  public static void forLoop(int, int);
    descriptor: (II)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=3, args_size=2
         0: iload_0
         1: istore_2
         2: iload_2
         3: iload_1
         4: if_icmpge     13
         7: iinc          2, 1
        10: goto          2
        13: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 6: 0
        line 9: 13
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            2      11     2     i   I
            0      14     0 start   I
            0      14     1 limit   I

  public static void whileLoop(int, int);
    descriptor: (II)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=3, args_size=2
         0: iload_0
         1: istore_2
         2: iload_2
         3: iload_1
         4: if_icmpge     13
         7: iinc          2, 1
        10: goto          2
        13: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 12: 0
        line 13: 2
        line 14: 7
        line 16: 13
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      14     0 start   I
            0      14     1 limit   I
            2      12     2     i   I
```

As you can see, the code section for both of these methods is *exactly* the same. However, when I decompile this class using [JD](http://jd.benow.ca/), it correctly produces:

```
public static void forLoop(int start, int limit) {
  for (int i = start; i < limit; i++) {}
}

public static void whileLoop(int start, int limit)
{
  int i = start;
  while (i < limit) {
    i++;
  }
}
```

How was it able to do this? The bytecode of these methods is exactly the same! Despite the fact that the `LineNumberTable` and `LocalVariableTable` attributes were different for each method, I am reluctant to believe that is the reason since those are not required attributes for the `Code` attribute of a method to contain (per [section 4.7 of The Java Language Specification, Java SE 8 Edition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7)).

Answer (score 5):

The line numbers and local variable scope.

`for` loop:

```
 LineNumberTable:
    line 6: 0
    line 9: 13
  LocalVariableTable:
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
        2      11     2     i   I
        0      14     0 start   I
        0      14     1 limit   I
```

`while` loop:

```
LineNumberTable:
        line 12: 0
        line 13: 2
        line 14: 7
        line 16: 13
  LocalVariableTable:
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
        0      14     0 start   I
        0      14     1 limit   I
        2      12     2     i   I
```

The `for` loop has fewer distinct lines of code - which makes sense because it wraps up the initialization and increment in one line.

Comment: Why does compiled code need to know local variable scope?

Comment: I don't think it *needs* to, but it certainly helps with debugging. I'd imagine that's the only reason it's there. There are probably tools that can remove it.

Comment: My guess is that it helps for utilizing the local variable list more efficiently. For example, if a local variable stored in index 2 falls out of scope, the compiler knows that it can re-use index 2 for another local variable. If indices were not re-used, the "max locals" for each method would be equivalent to the number of local variables declared in the method, *not* the maximum number of local variables visible in a certain scope within the method.

Comment: @MartinTuskevicius That can all be calculated at compile time.

Comment: @MartinTuskevicius That's all true but it describes compile-time operations.

Comment: @shmosel There is no scope information in the object file. There is debugging and stack trace information, but it isn't required by execution of the code.

Comment: @EJP Don't `Start` and `Length` indicate variable scope?